# How to access snapshot value outside of loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase with JavaScript and I want to assign `user.fcmkey` to an outside variable key.

The following is my code but doesn't access the key value and prints `NA`. How can I access snapshot value outside of the snapshot block.

```
var key="NA";

firebase.database().ref('users').child("1234567896").once('value', function(snap) {
    const user = snap.val()
    const userKey = snap.key;
    const myKey=user.fcmkey;
    key = myKey  
});
```

Comment: Where are you printing the value of `key`? Inside the database callback or outside of it?

Comment: use then promise to resolve the value outside of current scope

Comment: please wire down code. i m new in firebase.

Comment: @BAndroidDeveloper check the answer to use promise in your case

Comment: Fireabse APIs are asynchronous, and you need to be working with them using asynchronous programming techniques.  https://medium.com/@CodingDoug/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
function retData(){
 firebase.database().ref('users').child("1234567896").once('value', function(snap) {
const user = snap.val()
const userKey = snap.key;
const myKey=user.fcmkey;
key=myKey  
callMe();
});


function callMe(){
console.log(key);
};
```

The function `callMe()` will be called after retrieving all the data, and `console.log(key);` will give you value retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Promises can be used to resolve the value outside scope of current query.

```
let getKey = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.database().ref('users').child("1234567896").once('value', function(snap) {
            const user = snap.val()
            const userKey = snap.key;
            const myKey=user.fcmkey;
            resolve(myKey)
        });
    });
};

getKey.then(myKey => {
    console.log(myKey)
    // do something withkey
})
```

More on promise Please have a look at [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass those whole `snap` out to a function? BTW: The `.once` is a promise already so you can `.then` it.

```
var myKey;

firebase.database().ref('users').child("1234567896").once('value', function(snap) {
    if(snap){
      doMyThing(snap);
    }
});

function doMyThing(snap){
  myKey = snap.val().whateverKeyIsInDB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to access and save states as below...

```
const saveState = {
     key: false,
     anyKey: 'anyDatas'
    };
```

OR

```
 const saveState = {};
```

Then you can save your saves in the object

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child("1234567896").once('value', function(snap) {
    const user = snap.val()
    const userKey = snap.key;
    const myKey=user.fcmkey;
    saveState.key = myKey;
});
```

To access the state, do something like `alert(saveState.key);`